# How to intall Tomcat as a daemon on OS X?

Tags: java, macos, tomcat, daemon

How do I install Tomcat as a daemon on OS X?  It should run even when a user is not logged on.

I could probably survive installing Tomcat for a single users and having it run at log in, for now.  But long term I need it installed and running as a service on boot.

Comment: I suggest this belongs on serverfault.com.  It is about administration of a system, rather than just programming.  Happy to be overruled, though.

Comment: Hmmm....I'd buy that...let the close votes decide....

Comment: I do need to script the installation of the service, though.  It's all part of a webapp I am writing, and this is all about the installation and running of it.  Could go both ways.   Hmmm....

Comment: This is the direct link to the Tomcat documentation that covers this subject: http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatOnMacOS

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write your own LaunchDaemon script for it.

Launch Services can be used to set up user or system-based startup.

Comment: fantastic.  I found complete instructions for this at http://publicobject.com/2005/05/launchd-tomcat.html

Answer (score 2):

See [Updated for 2009](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/TomcatOnMacOS) at the bottom of the page for details on what is needed

Answer (score 0):

What Matthew and Objects said, but remember if you are integrating with [launchd](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/launchd.8.html#//apple_ref/doc/man/8/launchd), the script should not fork and exit.  See [Daemon Requirements](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Articles/LaunchOnDemandDaemons.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001762)

Comment: Thanks for the link, but that statement is incorrect.  "You must not fork your process **and have the parent process exit**."  One can fork, but there are expected behaviors when doing so--parent does not exit, and must not daemonize itself.