# How to install Hudson as a service on OS X?

Tags: macos, hudson, jenkins

Running [hudson](http://hudson-ci.org/) it is easy but currently the documentation is missing the tutorial for installing an running hudson as a daemon/service on OS X.

When you switch to production you need to assure that it is properly configured and secured.

Requirements:

- be able to run it on port 80
- not running as root (or at least not running the jobs as root)
- assure that it does properly start/stop on system restarts
- enable auto-upgrade, that works directly from the web interface.

The best, would be to have an installation script that downloads latest hudson and installs it.

We'll integrate the best answer to Hudson wiki.

Resources:

- http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Meet+Hudson
- http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Automated+Upgrade
- http://jrenard.info/blog/a-quick-but-working-startup-item-for-hudson-for-mac-os-x.html
- http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Installing+Hudson+as+a+Unix+daemon
- http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2009/02/10/hudson-now-good-behaving-unix-daemon

Comment: I think this really belongs on Serverfault or Superuser... that said i plan on following the question :-)

Comment: I hope you are not one of those who considers that configuring the continuous integration server is a task of the IT. If we move it to one of these servers we are killing it.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157844/how-to-intall-tomcat-as-a-daemon-on-os-x as once Tomcat is running, Hudson will work just fine running that way. If you'd like to reuse your existing Apache install and add Hudson to it, this http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html might be helpful.

Comment: I agree with sal, deploy it to an app server and most of your points are solved. I also agree with prodigitalson, setting up and securing the Hudson server is part of IT, configuring and using is a task for the users (in this case developers or deployers or QA).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct solution is to install hudson inside tomcat and make tomcat run as daemon

This will also meet the security requirements and allow you to upgrade hudson with ease.

Here is the full guide for OS X 10.6:
https://serverfault.com/questions/183496/full-guide-for-installing-tomcat-on-os-x/183527#183527

Comment: By the way, after some time I decided to replace OS X with Ubuntu for the server. It's easier to maintain.

Comment: Deploying in Tomcat is harder and will not allow automatic upgrades. The only possible advantage is that it is more secure but most build machines are internal to begin with so there is no real security risk.

Answer (score 12):

If you want a local Hudson to run on your Mac whenever you log in, try this.

You'll want to set up a launchctl plist for it; that should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
 <key>UserName</key>
 <string>yourid</string>
 <key>Label</key>
 <string>Hudson</string>
 <key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
   <dict>
     <key>HUDSON_HOME</key>
     <string>/Users/yourid/.hudson</string>
   </dict>
 <key>ProgramArguments</key>
 <array>
 <string>/usr/bin/java</string>
 <string>-jar</string>
 <string>/Users/yourid/Hudson/hudson.war</string>
 </array>
 <key>RunAtLoad</key>
 <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This assumes you've downloaded `hudson.war` to your home directory under `~/Hudson`, and that you want to run it as yourself (probably the best decisions.) Be sure that you define the `<UserName>` key or it will run as root!

### Starting on login

1. Save the above as `/Library/LaunchAgents/hudson.plist`
2. Start it the first time with

   sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchAgents/hudson.plist

or log out and back in, which will do the same thing automatically.

### Starting on reboot

1. Save the above as `/Library/LaunchDaemons/hudson.plist`
2. Start it the first time with

   sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/hudson.plist

or reboot your machine, which will do the same thing automatically.

### Restarting Hudson

Hudson can't automatically restart under OS X, so if you need to stop it, issue the restart command

```
launchctl unload -w path_to_plist
```

I have found that sometimes it doesn't stop on the first execution of `launchctl unload`; in those cases just issue the command again.

This will run under port 8080 as if you had run the command from the command line yourself, using the Winstone server built in to the `.war` file.

I realize this doesn't specifically answer the "run it on port 80" question, but for development on your own laptop, I suggest that this is a better option.

Comment: Thanks for the effort but this approach does not solve several requirements: including starting at system restart (not login!), port 80, ...

Comment: LaunchAgents in the /Library directory do start at system start.  To run on port 80 see the winstone command line options: http://winstone.sourceforge.net/#commandLine

Comment: @jdkoftinoff you mean LaunchDaemons, not LaunchAgents
 @Sorin-Sbarnea then it meets all your requirements

Comment: A better approach (as mentioned above by James) is to replace `LaunchAgents` with `LaunchDaemons`. This will run the service at system boot as root, as opposed to requiring you to log on and running it under your user.

Answer (score 2):

The tiny solution I had (which also starts at login) was this:
First run hudson manually once (so it builds it's .hudson dir).
create a **hudson.command** file somewhere on your machine in OSX with content a little like this:

```
nohup java -jar .hudson/hudson.war --httpPort=8080 &
```

Then, open up system preferences, select your user, and then Login Items. Click the "+" button, and you'll be able to select the command with finder.

Next time you log in, hudson will have started.

Disadvantages:

- Hudson has no specific user - it's just you
- hudson is on port 8080
- Hudson restarts mean finding the process, killing it and starting the hudson.command file again.
- Hudson starts only once a user has logged in.

Comment: I believe you meant to say "create a hudson.command file", not a folder.