# Startup Jenkins service automatically on system reboot

Tags: macos, jenkins, continuous-integration, auto-build

I want to start up the Jenkins service installed on my mac automatically while system reboots after power loss. Can anyone please suggest to me how we can restart Jenkins automatically.

Comment: Did you try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715606/how-to-install-hudson-as-a-service-on-os-x

Comment: Thanks Bruno Lavit, the link u provided its all for manually restarting the service i think, do u have any idea on automatically restart after rebooting the mac.

Comment: I had a look on Google and I don't find any solution for the moment :(

Comment: Fixed English to make it easier to read for others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [OS X installer provided for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Thanks+for+using+OSX+Installer) will create a service to start it automatically after reboot.

The service uses launchd to run a scheduled job that checks whether Jenkins is running and starts it if not.  There are a couple of links to further details at the top of the Jenkins Wiki page, but [this page](http://nathangrigg.net/2012/07/schedule-jobs-using-launchd/) may be a better overview for you.

Comment: Thanks **gareth_bowles**, I gone through above OSX Installer page there i am unable to find any info. related to automatically starting the jenkins service, Can you please explain me bit clear if u get some time.

Comment: Amended my answer to link to details on the MacOS launch daemon, which controls the Jenkins service.