# Unable to make hudson run after restart

Tags: hudson

I am trying to setup hudson on our mac machine to work as a central server for building our jobs.
I tried following steps given in this link and created and loaded the plist files as well-
[How to install Hudson as a service on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715606/how-to-install-hudson-as-a-service-on-os-x)

but still unbale to make it as server not getting start even.
Can anyone help in it?
I just want to setup hudson on mac and whenever i restart it should automatically restart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have followed all steps as per link-

[How to install Hudson as a service on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3715606/how-to-install-hudson-as-a-service-on-os-x)

but the sudo load/unload command should be not entered with sudo, as i was already a root user, that was actually causing the path permission issues.